# How to disable specific days in UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, calendar, uidatepicker

I have a `UIDatePicker` that should show only specific days, like all Sundays and Mondays, and disable all other dates, The user can select only Sunday and Monday from this week, next week, the week after, to, let's say, 2020.

Is that even possible with `UIDatePicker`, or even any custom control?

Comment: Your best option is a `UIPickerView` will just the dates you want.

Comment: I don't know the dates, I know the days that I must not show, like I have too disable weekends or holidays, its totally dynamic @rmaddy

Comment: You have to calculate the list of valid dates. You have no choice if you want to make this work.

Comment: Lets see if someone have an easier solution

Comment: The only option with `UIDatePicker` is what Leo posted (and now deleted because you didn't like that solution). So you must write your own custom control or use `UIPickerView`. Either way you must build your own list of valid dates. Even if you `UIDatePicker` did allow the disabling of specific days, you will still need to calculate which days are valid or not. So no matter what, you need to calculate a list of valid dates.

Comment: My friend Ive posted my questions an hour ago, im open to suggestions and im open to discuss any solution, I didn't say that I don't like his answer, the man is trying to help and I appreciate every single answer/comment @rmaddy

Comment: @rmaddy is correct here. You can't really do this with UIDatePicker you would have to use UIPickerView and create a data source for it that includes the dates that you want to be selectable.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use like this:

From below code you will get dates of all the **Sundays** from **2016-2018**,

```
let cal = Calendar.current
// Get the date of 2 years ago today
let stopDate = cal.date(byAdding: .year, value: -2, to: Date())!

// We want to find dates that match on Sundays at midnight local time
var comps = DateComponents()
comps.weekday = 1 // Sunday

// Enumerate all of the dates
cal.enumerateDates(startingAfter: Date(), matching: comps, matchingPolicy: .previousTimePreservingSmallerComponents, repeatedTimePolicy: .first, direction: .backward) { (date, match, stop) in
    if let date = date {
        if date < stopDate {
            stop = true // We've reached the end, exit the loop
        } else {
            print("\(date)") // do what you need with the date
        }
    }
}
```

The logic is simple. Make an array of this is in your required `dateFormat` and show that in `pickerView` which will eventually work as `datePicker` for you.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible. You have to create custom date picker based on UIPickerView.

Comment: as a part of my question, I quote: Is that even possible with UIDatePicker, or even any custom control?

Answer (score -3):

**There is a way to do it** with just the `UIDatePicker`!

Lets say you have a `minTime` that is `January 16 10:00AM`

You would do something like this:

```
let picker = UIDatePicker()
picker.minimumDate = minTime
picker.maximumDate = minTime.changing(.hour, value: 23).changing(.minute, value: 59)
```

Then the picker will be stuck to that date.
Hope this helps someone!